# Jquery Drop Down Menu. The sub menu disappears when clicked. So, How to make the submenu stays when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Using jquery to show the submenu when menu(members)clicked. The toggle works when I click the Member menu and the problem is, when I click the submenu it will disappear, so I want it to stay when clicked. How to do that in javascript?...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e)
        {
            $('.has-sub').click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('tap')
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">WORKOUT <span>FITNESS CENTER</span></a></div>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Walk-In</a></li>
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Members</a>             
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                    </ul>       
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">
            SOME CONTENT YAY
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300italic,300);
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #858585;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 15px;  
}
.logo a{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #070807;

}
.logo a span{
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1AC93A;
}
nav{
    width: 250px;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: #171717;
    float: left;
}
#content {
    width: :auto;
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    padding: 15px
}
nav li{
    list-style: none;

}
nav li a{
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #030303;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
/*nav ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;

}*/
nav ul li.tap > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the events on child bubble up to the parent when clicked, to stop this add a click event to the child element and call `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling up to the parent being `.has-sub`:

```
$(".has-sub ul").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3rj3Lnw/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `sub` class to the ul from the li

Try:

```
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Walk-In</a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Members</a> 
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">Subscr</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Inventory</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">SOME CONTENT YAY</div>
</div>
  $('.has-sub').click(function(e){
       if ($(e.target).parents('.sub').length == 0 ){
        $(this).toggleClass('tap');
       }
    });
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9ynq7og/

Comment: Thanks for the respond bro :)

Comment: It works! thanks :) there are lot of ways now :) appreciate a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. i have added id into main menu and while click check for target id and base on this you can perform appropriate action

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.has-sub').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id)
      $(this).toggleClass('tap')
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300italic,300);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #858585;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.logo a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #070807;
}
.logo a span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1AC93A;
}
nav {
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background-color: #171717;
  float: left;
}
#content {
  width: : auto;
  margin-left: 250px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  padding: 15px
}
nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
nav li a {
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #030303;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
/*nav ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;

}*/

nav ul li.tap > ul {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo"><a href="#">WORKOUT <span>FITNESS CENTER</span></a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="container">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Walk-In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-sub">
                        <a href="#" id='id1'>Members</a> 
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Subscr</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">asdasd</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">asdasd</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Inventory</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="content">
                SOME CONTENT YAY
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this...

```js
  $(document).ready(function(e)
     {
      $('.test').click(function(e){
        if($(this).hasClass("test1"))
             {
               e.stopPropagation();
             }else
               {
                $(this).toggleClass('tap');
               }
         });
     });
```

```css
**CSS**

    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300italic,300);
    *{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
     font-family: 'Open Sans';
    }
    
    a{
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    header{
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #858585;
    }
    
    .logo {
     float: left;
     margin-top: 9px;
     margin-left: 15px;  
    }
    
    .logo a{
     font-size: 1.3em;
     color: #070807;
     
    }
    .logo a span{
     font-weight: 300;
     color: #1AC93A;
    }
    
    nav{
     width: 250px;
     height: calc(100% - 50px);
     background-color: #171717;
     float: left;
    }
    
    #content {
     width: :auto;
     margin-left: 250px;
     height: calc(100% - 50px);
     padding: 15px
    }
    
    nav li{
     list-style: none;
    
    }
    
    nav li a{
     color: #ccc;
     display: block;
     padding: 10px;
     font-size: 0.8em;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
     -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
     -moz-transition: 0.2s;
     -o-transition: 0.2s;
     transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    nav li a:hover{
     background-color: #030303;
     color: #fff;
     padding-left: 80px;
    }
    
    nav ul li ul {
     display: none;
    }
    
    /*nav ul li:hover > ul{
     display: block;
    
    }*/
    
    nav ul li.tap > ul{
     display: block;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Dashboard</title>
     
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
    
   

    </head>
    <body>
    
     <header>
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">WORKOUT <span>FITNESS CENTER</span></a></div>
     </header>
     <div id="container">
      <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Walk-In</a></li>
        <li class="has-sub test"><a href="#">Members</a>    
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#" class='test test1'>Subscr</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class='test test1'>asdasd</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class='test test1'>asdasd</a></li>
           </ul>       
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
    
      <div id="content">
       SOME CONTENT YAY
      </div>
     </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Wow! nice :) I liked it. Thanks!

Comment: you can appreciate this answer.. if its what you want

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a jquery function.

```
$('.has-sub ul').click(function(){
        return false
    });
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyc45p5u/1/) for your requirement